# JS Bug on Safari : Unexpected token '='

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm using jsio (jslibs - http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/jsio) and am running into a bug on Safari.  **Unexpected token '='**

The problem is with this part of the code.

```
this.debugPath = function(path) { return path; }

// IE6 won't return an anonymous function from eval, so use the function constructor instead
var rawEval = (typeof eval('(function(){})') == 'undefined')
            ? function(src, path) { return (new Function('return ' + src))(); }
            : function(src, path) { var src = src + '\n//@ sourceURL=' + path; return window.eval(src); };

// provide an eval with reasonable debugging
this.eval = function(code, path, origCode) {
......................
```

The problem seems to be at the line where `rawEval` is being assigned. Commenting it out caused the error to shift elsewhere. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Help?

Thanks.

Comment: `function(src, path) { var src = src ... }` might be buggy.  You're using `src` once to declare a local variable, but it isn't a local variable.  You just end up overwriting the formal parameter of the same name.

Comment: Btw, `new Function(...)` binds in global scope, whereas under ES3 `window.eval` binds in the calling scope, so these two are not equivalent.  One way to work around the IE6 eval problem, is to prepend the string `"0,"` to the expression text you're evaluating.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Do you mean the following? Tried but didn't work.

    `var rawEval = function(src, path) {`
 `return eval("0," + src + '\n//@ sourceURL=' + path);`
    `};`

Comment: yes, something like that has solved the problem for me.  What is `src` and what result do you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for future reference if anyone (including me) runs into this problem again.

The error that Safari throws in my case is spurious or at the least pretty ambiguous.

I had defined a class in one of my libraries. And I didn't want to store a handle/reference to an object of that class. So, I'd done something like:

```
function reply(...) {
    new ClassName(.....).onHide = bind(...);
    ..........
}
```

When I changed it to the following, Safari stopped complaining.

```
function reply(...) {
    var dg = new ClassName(......);
    dg.onHide = bind(...);
    ..............
}
```

Declaring a new object and defining one of its member properties (or functions) could be a problem.